# how to design a board in tkinter canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I want to design a 9x9 board in tkinter canvas. Each rectangle should have a width and height of 30 (pixels?). Do I always have to use the pixel coordinates for drawing shapes onto the canvas or is there a more relative way possible? For example, my board looks like this:

```
class TkCanvas(tk.Canvas):
   RECT_WIDTH = 30

   def __init__(self, parent, width=600, height=600, columns=9, rows=9):
      super().__init__(parent, width=width, height=height)
      self.columns=columns
      self.rows=rows
      self.board = [[None for col in range(columns)] for row in range(rows)]

   def draw_board(self, x1=0, x2=0,y1=RECT_WIDTH,y2=RECT_WIDTH):
        for col in range(self.columns):
            for row in range(self.rows):
                x1 = col * self.RECT_WIDTH
                y1 = (self.rows-1-row) * self.RECT_WIDTH
                x2 = x1 + self.RECT_WIDTH
                y2 = y1 + self.RECT_WIDTH
                tag = f"tile{col}{row}"
                self.board[row][col] = self.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill="white", tags=tag, outline="black")
                self.tag_bind(tag,"<Button-1>", lambda e, i=col, j=row: self.get_location(e,i,j))

   def get_location(self, event, i, j):
        print (i, j)

   def get_x_coord(self, x):
        return x * self.RECT_WIDTH
    
   def get_y_coord(self, y):
        return y * self.RECT_WIDTH
```

Now when I want to draw a shape I get the exact coordinates `x0`,`y0` first with `get_x_coord` and `get_y_coord` and then calculate `x1` and `y1` by adding the `RECT_WIDTH`.

Is there a cleaner way to draw the shapes onto the canvas? Something where I would only have to pass in the coordinates, eg. (4,5) and it would automatically draw it in the right rectangle or do I always have to make these calculations?

Comment: You can define a function accepting `row` and `column` as arguments and convert the row and column to x and y inside the function.  *Yes you still need to do the coordinates conversion*, but it is more readable to use the function to draw the shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to produce a grid board and yours works fine.

Using relative offsets to position squares and pieces is easy in tkinter Canvas,
just use `canvas.move(itemID, xoffset, yoffset)`. You can also move or scale the
entire board by using `canvas.addtag_all('somename')` then `canvas.scale('somename', 0, 0, s, s)`. Where s is a float s > 0

The following code creates class `drawBoard` that can be instantiated using
just two values or by using many control values and demonstrates how to use
relative coordinates to build a scalable board.

The board is created by drawing all rectangles at (0, 0, w, h) then moving them
to location via relative values (x, y).
Once all squares have been created the entire board is scaled to size.

Method `get_location` displays user input.

```py
import tkinter as tk

back, fore, draw, wall, light = "white", "blue", "red", "black", "yellow"

class drawBoard(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(
        self, w, h, columns = 9, rows = 9, scale = 1, line = 1, border = 1):

        super().__init__()
        
        self.withdraw()
        self.configure(background = light, borderwidth = border)
        # pre calculate sizes and set geometry
        self.store = dict()
        # small change to w, h and wide, high
        x, y, w, h = 0, 0, w + line, h + line
        wide = w * columns * scale + (line==1)
        high = h * rows * scale + (line==1)
        self.geometry(f"{wide + border * 2 }x{high + border * 2}")
        # minimal Canvas
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(
            self, width = wide, height = high, background = back,
            borderwidth = 0, highlightthickness = 0, takefocus = 1)
        self.canvas.grid(sticky = tk.NSEW)
        # draw the board
        for row in range(rows):
            for column in range(columns):
                item = self.canvas.create_rectangle(
                    0, 0, # removed line, line
                    w, h, width = line,
                    fill = back, outline = fore)

                self.canvas.move(item, x, y)
                self.store[item] = (row, column)
                x = x + w
            x, y = 0, y + h
        # tag all items and scale them
        self.canvas.addtag_all("A")
        self.canvas.scale("A", 0, 0, scale, scale)
        # bind user interaction
        self.bind("<Button-1>", self.get_location)
        self.after(500, self.complete)


    def complete(self):
        self.resizable(0, 0)
        self.deiconify()


    def get_location(self, ev):
        # find user selection
        item = self.canvas.find_closest(
            self.canvas.canvasx(ev.x), self.canvas.canvasy(ev.y))[0]
        # flip color for demo
        fill = self.canvas.itemcget(item, "fill")
        self.canvas.itemconfig(item, fill = [draw, back][fill == draw])
        # extract and display info
        row, column = self.store[item]
        x, y, w, h = self.canvas.coords(item)
        print(f"{row}, {column} >> {x}, {y}, {w-x}, {h-y}")

if True:
    # the easiest way
    app = drawBoard(30, 30)
else:
    # Or with lots of control
    app = drawBoard(
        30, 30, columns = 40, rows = 20, scale = 1, line = 1, border = 1)
```

Comment: when i click on the second rectangle I get the following print outs: `0, 1 >> 31.0, 1.0, 29.0, 29.0`. `x` seems to be 31 instead of 30, and `w` and `h` seem to be 29 instead of 30. Is that because of the border width of 1?

Comment: When you wrap some object with a border of 1 you would normally have to add 2 to the width and height. The rectangle object only increases by the size of the outline. A small change to the code should make this clear